# Form Recogniser - 404 resource not found when calling Analyse Form API

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-form-recognizer

I used the labelling tool to train my model and successfully generated the modelID. When tried the "Get List Custom Models", successfully received the list of models I trained, but when tried to call the "Analyse Form" API, got the error message 404 "resource not found".
Also tried with the logic app - passed the modelID and the link as per specification:
https://something.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models/modelID/analyze

but again got the error 404. Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form Recognizer Logic App is currently using Form Recognizer v1.0 (preview) and models that were trained with v2.0 API or the labeling tool are not available via the Logic App Form Recognizer connector. When calling the API please call the v2.0 API using the same resource ID and key you used in the labeling tool project.